# what will be the query for the following?

Tags: php, mysql, database

here is the sql for the three tables

```
CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
  `cust_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `reservation_id` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `car_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `total` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pulocation` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dolocation` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pudate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dodate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `putime` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `dotime` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `car` (
  `car_id` int(25) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `car_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rental` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `details` text NOT NULL,
  `date_added` date NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;



CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `cust_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`cust_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

cust_id and car_id are the foreign key from car and customer table.So i have to write a query to check whether the car is available between the pudate and dodate from the reservation table.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your code, provide sample data and desired output and what you've tried so far so that we can see your effort.

Comment: m trying to join the tables using inner join and than checking whether the date is available or not but its still not working

Comment: Your cust_id and car_id are actually NOT foreign keys; you might want to fix that.  Plus, latin1 will mangle text with accents (commonly: people and place names); consider using UTF-8, instead.  Finally, you should post your attempted solution(s) into your question's body so we know you at least tried to solve it on your own at least a few times.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you made a failing attempt yet, or just planning on someone doing the work for you? There is a difference between helped and spoon fed.

Comment: Also learn how to **[upvote/accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** answers so that StackOverflow members be more willing to help you.